# How to search & replace IP portion in a text file with IP:PORT format based on a preceding search key?

Tags: shell, sed

In my file, my script need to search `marker_strings` and then update the next text having `IP:PORT` format after it without changing its `PORT` value.

Here is an example scenario:

```
marker-a should use 600.0.0.100
marker-b should use 700.0.0.200
```

#sample file (before)

```
server marker-a 100.0.0.10:11648 check
server marker-b 100.0.0.11:11111 check
server marker-a 100.0.0.10:11648 check
server marker-b 100.0.0.11:11111 check
```

#sample file (after)

```
server marker-a 600.0.0.100:11648 check
server marker-b 700.0.0.200:11111 check
server marker-a 600.0.0.100:11648 check
server marker-b 700.0.0.200:11111 check
```

I've tried this based on other answers closest to this scenario and found this but nothing in output shows any changes.

```
sed -e '/^ *marker-a / s/ [^# ]/ 600.0.0.100/' input.txt
```

```
sed -e 's/^"marker-a" .*$/"marker-a 600.0.0.100"/' input.txt
```

Comment: My apologies, Ed. I actually had second thoughts about editing this same entry. I edited/reverted it now to its original requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    mark2ip["marker-a"] = "600.0.0.100"
    mark2ip["marker-b"] = "700.0.0.200"
}
$2 in mark2ip {
    sub(/[^:]+/,mark2ip[$2],$3)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
server marker-a 600.0.0.100:11648 check
server marker-b 700.0.0.200:11111 check
server marker-a 600.0.0.100:11648 check
server marker-b 700.0.0.200:11111 check
```

The above assumes the new IP addresses don't contain `&`s (i.e. a backreference metachar) which is reasonable since it's an IP address. In general for a replacement that'll work for any characters just change `sub(/[^:]+/,mark2ip[$2],$3)` to `sub(/[^:]+/,"",$3); $3=mark2ip[$2] $3`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ed. Using your main script worked for my use case. I'm still a newbie with `awk` so I would need to read up more on the basics.

Comment: @stealthcoder you're welcome. I highly recommend the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, for anyone wanting to learn awk.

Comment: Thank you, Ed.  I'm starting to read that book now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```bash
sed -E \
 -e 's/(marker-a[[:space:]]*)[^:]+/\1600.0.0.100/' \
 -e 's/(marker-b[[:space:]]*)[^:]+/\1700.0.0.200/' \
 input.txt
```

Here we use two similar expressions. `(marker-a[[:space:]]*)` matches marker and following whitespace symbols into group `\1`, later used in substitution, and `[^:]+` matches everything that follows till `:`.